# Longest substring in a large set of strings

Tags: c

I have a huge fixed library of text strings, and a frequently changing input string s.  I need to find the longest matching substring from any string in the library to s, starting from the beginning of string s, in minimal time.  In a perfect world, I would also return the next longest match from the library, and the next best, and so on.  This is not the longest common string problem - I'm not looking for the longest common string for all the strings in the library...  I just need a pairwise best substring between s and each string in the vast library as fast as possible.

Comment: Should matching strings be matching at their first characters, e.g. `abcd` and `abef`? Or `abcd` and `bcde` is also a match?

Answer (score 1):

After rereading, I think the best way to do this is probably to build a trie or a prefix tree of your big library of strings, then match `s` against that.

This has a couple of advantages. First, it stores your big library in (at least somewhat) compressed form. Second, it more or less automatically tells you all the strings that match a given input, not just the longest one.

It also fits your use case quite well -- while it takes quite a bit of work to build a trie or (especially) a prefix tree from the input, using it afterwards is quite fast.

Comment: This is basically a longest prefix matching search, for which a trie is a good fit. You iterate down the trie keying character by character on your input string until you can't go any further. If you hit a leaf node when or before you have exhausted your input string, then that is your match. If you're at a non-leaf node, then all strings descending from that node have whatever portion of your input string has been matched (possibly all of it) as a prefix

Comment: Just an aside, no red-black or any other tree in std C (AFAIK), also no hashing.  So bsearch is the only algorithm in the standard that you can use out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

sort your list ahead of time (i.e. compile time or before) then use bsearch

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/bsearch/

once you find your match, you can look behind and ahead in the vicinity to get as many "matches" as you want.

BTW, bsearch isn't necessarily the fastest because it passes the comparator function, but is in the standard C library.

Comment: Unless each longer string is an extension of each shorter string, this won't work. A longer string might match even when a shorter one doesn't.

Comment: @Jerry Wouldn't that be the case if they were sorted alphabetically?  Also, the OP gets to define the comparator function, so what "matches" is up to them.  I was assuming the substring was starting at position 0 of the strings in the list.  This may not be what the OP intended.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Yes, if it has to start from position 0, this would work nicely. I had assumed that was not required, but re-reading, I'm pretty sure you're right -- he does specify "starting from the beginning of string s".